# how do I recover mono-.NET4.5 runtime capability if I delete subdirectories such as /usr/lib/mono/2.0?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, .net, c#

On Ubuntu Linux 15.10 , how do I recover mono-.NET4.5 runtime capability only if I delete the following subdirectories /usr/lib/mono/2.0,/usr/lib/mono/3.5,/usr/lib/mono/4.0 and /usr/lib/mono/4.5 ? We would like to conserve disk space so a solution other than sudo apt-get install mono-complete is sought and preferred Also, I just tested sudo apt-get install libmono-system-data2.0-cil and it changed nothing.
  We do not need the mono mcs compiler or Monodevelop IDE tools as this a production environment.
  I have tried every answer in this Stack Overflow URL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490155/unable-to-run-net-app-with-mono-mscorlib-dll-not-found-version-mismatch and I am looking for a different solution.
 Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to refresh the Ubuntu Linux 15.10 repository to make, sudo apt-get install libmono-system4.0-cil,  install at least one package? Currently, this install outputs the following message: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded. If so, how do I refresh the repository? Thank you.

Comment: What if I build and install the libmono's tar release?